# How to set the plugin load order when updating the active_plugins option?

Tags: php

When using the `active_plugins` option to update the list of active plugins, is it possible to set the plugin load order? For example:

```
$plugins_to_activate = array(
    'my-plugin/my-plugin.php',
    'another-plugin/another-plugin.php'
);
update_option( 'active_plugins', $plugins_to_activate );
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if possible**, you should not do that. If plugin execution depends on load order then you do something terribly wrong.

** You can disable all plugins except for one that you will write and include the main plugin files in whatever order you want.

Comment: I'm unit testing my plugin and need a particular plugin (BuddyPress) to be available _before_ my code is executed.

Comment: I said in the answer, your code has bugs if it requires such a thing

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Imagine what would happen if I didn't load BuddyPress first and then I tried to use a BuddyPress function made available through their API?

Comment: You should generally not use any function outside your plugin before the `init` action is activated, probably even better to wait for `wp_loaded`.